# Деплой и проблема с очисткой сессии в Symfony3 + Heroku

Tags: сессия, symfony2, composer, symfony3, heroku

Разрабатывая проект, при добавлении нового функционала я обновляю все файлы на 2 серверах: рабочий(платный хостинг) и тестовый(бесплатный - heroku). Деплой на платный хостинг производится при помощи ftp(там нет ssh), а на тестовый при помощи команды: git push heroku master.

Деплой на тестовый хостинг происходит чаще, по нескольку раз в день, где заказчик проверяет все функции. Проблема заключается в том, что при обновлении файлов на тестовом сервере каждый раз очищается сессия и заказчик ругается что ему надоело каждый раз заходить в систему для проверки функций, а происходит выбрасивание из системы автоматически (удаляются сессии) и он хочет оставаться в системе.

Вопрос: влияет ли на это composer и можно это ли это исправить? Влияет ли на это команда композера, которая очищает кеш? Или проблема сугубо в сервере heroku и он сам автоматически затирает сессию, соответственно это не исправить, если только не сменить хостинг?

Comment: Храните сессии в Redis, Memcached или в используемой вами базе данных. Эти хранилища гарантируют сохранность данных между деплоями. Похоже, что в настоящий момент вы используете файловую систему для хранения сессий. [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) не хранит изменения: каждый `dyno` получает свою собственную копию такой "временной" файловой системы и все изменения в ней будут проигнорированы в момент остановки/перезапуска `dyno`

Comment: Подробнее о настройке хранения сессий рассказывает раздел документации [PHP Session Handling on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions). Там же можно получить более развернутое описание причины такого поведения.

Comment: @angy_v думаю это может решить проблему. Можете описать то же самое как ответ чтобы я смог его принять.

Comment: Оформил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что в настоящий момент вы используете файловую систему для хранения сессий. [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) не хранит изменения: каждый `dyno` получает свою собственную копию такой "временной" файловой системы и все изменения в ней будут проигнорированы в момент остановки/перезапуска

Храните сессии в `Redis`, `Memcached` или в используемой вами базе данных. Эти хранилища гарантируют сохранность данных между деплоями.

Подробнее о настройке хранения сессий рассказывает раздел документации [PHP Session Handling on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-sessions). Там же можно получить более развернутое описание причины такого поведения.